driver "self['prop']" not working in 4.2.2?
I want to reference a "current object" custom property in a shader node driver via a scripted self["Custom Property"].
I have tried the solution provided in this answer in my 4.2.2 app (turn on "Auto Run Python Scripts" but I still get an error:

Error in PyDriver: expression failed: self["EmissionValue"] For
target: (type=NodeTree, name="Shader Nodetree",
property=default_value, property_index=-1)


I have created custom properties of the same name (here: "EmissionValue") at the object, data, and Material node levels, just to try any avenue that might work.
Still no luck.   What color salt do I have to throw over my shoulder ;)
My example: 

Based on MvB's answer below and my console error message above, "self" point to the material's node_tree, so there is no way to get to the (possible shared) material's object's instance data.

It points to a node socket. From there you can use the node attribute to get to the node. Not sure even if you can get to the node tree... Now normally you could just read the node's rna or repr to see the name of its node tree, but on the evaluated copy, I don't know.

You get the error for node tree evaluation, but self is the node socket. Just use print(type(self)) in the driver and see what system console reports.

self refers to the socket.
Fortunately, rather than being an inelegant workaround, the alternative is an improvement, because it doesn't require security privileges:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

That solves the problem.    But ... I actually also put a custom property on the Material, with the same name.  Shouldn't that also have worked?

@james_t sorry, I got it wrong, apparently self is the socket, not the material. I checked for older versions too (same result) so not sure why I thought otherwise. And I don't know how to obtain the material from a node (self.node), since it's an evaluated copy and there's no original attribute to access the node...
